# How to get the dynamic expression

Tags: code-review, code-request

$$Z_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha Z_n}{1+Z_{n-1}}$$
How to write the above expression in Mathematica? I want to get say Z_100, Z_10 by that scheme. Can I call say $Z_{10}$ if $Z_{n+1}$ is given?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must initialize values of `z` for the function to be evaluated.  Moreover, never use upper-case letters as variables as they are likely to conflict with internal variables and functions.

```
\[Alpha] = 3;
z[0] = 0;
z[1] = 1;
z[n_] := \[Alpha] z[n - 1]/(1 + z[n - 2]);

ListPlot[Table[{i, z[i]}, {i, 1, 30}], Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: How to get the plot? What is this plot? Is it plot of z[0], z[1], ...z[30]?

Comment: @SkSarifHassan I added the instructions for making a plot.

Comment: Additional questions: for which values of Alpha is the solution finite? Which is the asymtotic value, which the frequency? (These questions assume linearisation of the equation).